Next Js "next": "14.2.3" Stating page is not working
I just created a Next.js "14.2.3" version project and I got this page. I didn't change anything my code and I got this error

What is the reason for this ???? I didn't change anything in my code...
This is my file structure

And this is my log

Please help me how to fix this issue.

src/app/page.tsx is localhost:3000/ not localhost:3000/en

it automatically redirect to localhost:3000/en

test it in an ignorant window

how did you do that

You need to clear your browser cache

or try it in incognito

I tried to edit this post, and received this error: "Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results". This comes about because information that is text has been screen-shotted and supplied as a picture. Please always supply console information as text e.g. in a code block. Images of text is not as helpful.

please visit
http://localhost:3000/
to view homepage insted of
http://localhost:3000/en
if it is automatically redirect it means route is cached, so you need to empty cache and hard reload from browser, then you can visit

